# How to determine the CFM of a dust collector

Tags: dust-collection

I am looking at purchasing a used dust collector and don't know how to calculate the CFM. It has a 7.5hp motor with 1760 rpm, it has an 8' top pulley and a 8" bottom pulley, can you help me find out how much CFM it would create?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  I am not certain if  there is enough information.  I believe the cfm is also going to be dependent upon other factors including the intake size and the configuration of the fan box as well as the motor size.  Is this a machine for which you can check with the manufacturer?

Comment: Search"calculate CFM" to see how it really depends.

Comment: Hi - Post the manufacturer and model number. Your question depends on the size of the inlet/outlet and the size of the impeller. Attach a picture?

Comment: Its an 8" inlet and 8" outlet. I don't know the manufacturer as its been repainted.